# css for certain select input class

Tags: css, select

Im using several select box in my form and integrated the combobox plugin

https://github.com/danielfarrell/bootstrap-combobox

the problem of this plugin the dropdown menu is not 100% width

[image]

i fixed it with this and its working fine

```
<style>

.dropdown-menu
{
 width: 100%;
}

</style>


<select class="combobox">
  <option></option>
  <option value="PA">Pennsylvania</option>
  <option value="CT">Connecticut</option>
  <option value="NY">New York</option>
  <option value="MD">Maryland</option>
  <option value="VA">Virginia</option>
</select>
```

but right now one of my date-time select input is not working

how do i edit this css so it will efect select box with combobox class only

```
<style>

.dropdown-menu
{
 width: 100%;
}

</style>
```

Comment: Where is the HTML code using the `dropdown-menu` class? Are you using that class more often?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap all of the boxes in a container with a particular class and define it using the parent class. Ex:

```
<div class="xyz-class"><select class="combobox"></select></div>
```

Now you can define this using css using

```
.xyz-class .dropdown-menu { width: 100% }
```

Comment: Happy to help. Feel free to ask if you have more questions.

Answer (score 1):

What element(s) has the class dropdown-menu?

You need to find something to differentiate the combobox drop down elements from the other select elements you don't want styled.

For example you could add a class such as dateTimeSelect to your date-time select elements and change your CSS style rule to:

.dropdown-menu:not(.dateTimeSelect)